# How to I register a domain name that has been registered?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

I am writing to ask about a domain name I wish to own. I have contacted the domain owner (by performing a WhoIS search) by email and have not received a reply. I have tried contacting him for over a year.

I have also contacted the domain registrar (`namecheap.com`) where the domain is registered, and they have told me that they cannot contact him on my behalf, and told me to contact him using the email address.

Are there any ways of securing this domain name for myself? I have waited for it to expire but unfortunately, it automatically renewed!

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get a registered domain is through buying it from its current owner. Contact current owner and tell him your offer, if he is interested he will sell domain to you.